# Teradara SQL - Operation with max-min dates

Tags: sql, teradata

suppose I have the following data frame in Reradata SQL. 
How can I get the variation between the highest and lowest date, at user level? Regards

```
Initial table
   user    date   price
    1       1-1       10
    1       2-1       20
    1       3-1       30 
    2       1-1       12
    2       2-1       22
    2       3-1       32 
    3       1-1       13
    3       2-1       23
    3       3-1       33

 Final table

user   var_price
1       30/10-1
2       32/12-1
3       33/13-1
```

Comment: What is last part of final data "-1" belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT B.[user],
CAST(SUM(B.max_price) AS VARCHAR)+'/'+CAST(SUM(B.min_price) AS VARCHAR)+ '-1' var_price,
SUM(B.max_price)/SUM(B.min_price) -1 calculated_var_price
FROM
(
    SELECT *    FROM 
    (
        SELECT [user],0 max_price,price min_price,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [user] ORDER BY DATE)  RN
        FROM your_table
    )A WHERE RN = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT [user],price max_price,0 min_price, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [user] ORDER BY DATE DESC)  RN
        FROM your_table
    )A WHERE RN = 1
)B
GROUP BY B.[user]
```

Output is-

```
user    var_price    calculated_var_price
1       30/10-1      2
2       32/12-1      1
3       33/13-1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select user, max(price) / min(price) - 1
from t
group by user;
```

Your values are monotonically increasing, so `max()` and `min()` seems like the simplest solution.

EDIT:

You can use window functions:

```
select user, max(last_price) / max(first_price) - 1
from (select t.*,
             first_value(price) over (partition by user order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current_row) as first_price,
             first_value(price) over (partition by user order by date desc rows between unbounded preceding and current_row) as last_price
      from t
     ) t
group by user;
```

Comment: Not necessarily, for real data the order of values may not be respected. The first may be greater than the last.

Comment: ok, even if the order of values is varying, the query should run fine

Answer (score 1):

```
select user
  ,price as first_price
  ,last_value(price)
   over (paritition by user
         order by date
         rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as last_price
from mytab
qualify 
  row_number() -- lowest date only
  over (paritition by user
        order by date) = 1
```

This returns the row with the lowest date and adds the price of the latest date